# The output of the following program is 1,3,3 can someone explain it how?

Tags: java

The output of the following program is 1,3,3 can someone explain it how?
will it consider 10.25 as a object to the method argument?

```
public class Test {
  void methodOfTest(int i) {
    System.out.println(1);
  }

  void methodOfTest(Integer I) {
    System.out.println(2);
  }

  void methodOfTest(Object o) {
    System.out.println(3);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();

    t.methodOfTest(10);

    t.methodOfTest(10.25);

    t.methodOfTest(new Double("25.25"));
  }
}
```

Comment: "_Why will it consider 10.25 as a object_" Because it is not an `int` or `Integer`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
t.methodOfTest(10);
```

10 is interpreted as `int` literal, so `methodOfTest(int i)` is called

```
t.methodOfTest(10.25);
```

There is no method, that takes a `double`, so the only method where `10.25` fits in is `methodOfTest(Object o)`

```
t.methodOfTest(new Double("25.25"));
```

Here we have a `Double` object, but again, no method is found that takes a `Double`, so the only method that takes this is again `methodOfTest(Object o)`.

Therefore your output is `1,3,3`.

Answer (score 2):

It does not consider 10.25 to be an object. It does consider it to be assignment-convertible to an Object reference, by boxing conversion to a Double reference followed by widening reference conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The boxing answers are absolutely correct. 
I just wanted to add this: you were perhaps expecting an automatic (implicit) conversion from Double to Integer, but such a conversion must be declared explicitly (casting Double to Integer). 
Without an explicit conversion, your Double value is interpreted as an Object (since you provided that method overload), which is the base class of about everything.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info alex!

Answer (score -1):

Because 10.25 can be converted to a Double. (boxing into Double)
So the constructor of Double will be called with 10.25 as parameter and will be passed to the method : void methodOfTest(Object o).